# Renaming functions in visual studio 2015 for C#

Tags: c#, rename

We just migrated to visual studio 2015. We were using 2010 and with 2010, I was able to hit f2 and type a new name for a function/variable and it would apply to all instances. Now in vs 2015 when I hit f2 there is no where to type the name to rename the variable/method to. Sorry if this sounds silly but I have been puzzling now a couple daze...

Comment: For refactoring? `Ctrl+R,R`

Comment: Don't you just type it inline now, instead of via the popup box? In any event, Ctrl+R,R should do it. Or just refactor from context menu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe in 2015, you simply need to rename the variable where it is, and you'll see a dotted box or line appear around your variable, you can right click and do "Rename variable" which will rename it everywhere it's used. Same with methods.

Answer (score 1):

There is the other binding for renaming that I believe is:

```
Ctrl + R, Ctrl + R
```

Answer (score 1):

You can right-click over the function name and choose Refactor > Rename and go from there.  It will ask you if you want to apply it solution-wide and allow you to preview as well.

Edit - this is the same as @TheLethalCoder answer, just not keyboard shortcut

Answer (score 0):

TheLethalCoder is correct. Put your cursor on the class/method/variable name and hit

```
Ctrl + R, Ctrl + R
```

and you'll be prompted for the new name and shown a list of places in your code base that it'll be changed.

Answer (score 0):

For VS 2015 onwards, the renaming is

CTRL +. for renaming.